# Windows Server 2019 thinks wrong driver is "Best"

Tags: windows, drivers, backup, lto

We recently upgraded from Windows Server 2008 R2 to Windows Server 2019.

This slowed our tape backup severely, doubling the time to complete our backup to a Quantum LTO tape drive. Searching for updated drivers, I find on [Quantum's website](https://www.quantum.com/serviceandsupport/softwareanddocumentationdownloads/lto-8hh/index.aspx) a 3.8.0.1 driver that is labeled as "for Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016/2019", in addition, there is a 3.8.0.2 driver labeled "for all current Windows OS's except Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016/2019". Windows installs the 3.8.0.2 driver, and if I attempt to use the 3.8.0.1 driver, it refuses, saying, "The best driver for your device are already installed." How can I install the proper 3.8.0.1 driver??

[image]

[image]

[Drivers in use](https://mega.nz/file/stBiABrD#byHtUJIT4oauCDoAvtr6sGVS1K9zvxAUfPvjL-x3l0U)

Comment: Looking at the .inf file for the ` 3.8.0.2` driver, it most definitely, is not compatible with Windows 10 and/or Windows Server 2016/2019.  Have you attempted to use Device Manager to point to the correct .inf file?  I would not read anything into the version number of the driver being "newer".  Based on the .inf it shouldn't be possible for Windows 10 to even install the `3.8.0.2` there isn't even an entry for Windows 10.

Comment: The fully manual driver selection should _always_ work. Tried that yet?

Comment: You might have to provide us file information on the file that is installed so we can compared it to the file in the proper archive.

Comment: The 3.8.0.2 driver is possibly what it was using when the server ran Windows Server 2008 R2. We upgraded to Windows Server 2012, then immediately upgraded to Windows Server 2019.

I have tried both "Update Driver" though the device properties and right clicked in device manager, choosing "Update Driver". If there is another "manual" process to update a driver, I am unware of how to do so.

Comment: I have added the driver files in use and device dialog boxes..

Comment: You have two choices.  You can manually replace the driver yourself or use "Uninstall Device" and use the option to delete the driver then install the proper driver.  In all honestly they are likely identical.  You will want to avoid installing the optional device driver through Windows Update.

Comment: After selecting _Update Driver_ you must select _Browse my computer for drivers_ and then _Let me pick from a list of available drivers on my computer_, then _Have Disk_. So, again: Tried that yet?

Answer (score 0):

Update: Manually copying the two driver files and overwriting the current two files resulted in the system still showing the drivers as version 3.8.0.2. Uninstalling the device and reinstalling, did result in it using the proper 3.8.0.1 drivers. This did not result in any improvement in the backup time. So as Ramhound suggested they seem identical.

I appreciate all the help!